# Mutually coupled inductor modelling in cadence

Tags: cadence, mutual-inductance

I used two methods to model two mutually coupled coils.

**Method: 1)** Using 'mind' cell from analogLib. It basically lets you define a coupling coefficient k value.
**Method:2)** Using 'Xfmr' cell from analogLib which basically lets you define turn ratio.

I am getting different results if I use method1 ('mind' cell) in Z11 plot. 
The real part of input impedance (Re[Z11]) shows frequency dependent behaviour. But Re[Z11] = just the resistors and should be a constant line in Re[Z11] vs. f plot. 
If I use method2, Re[Z11] is constant wrt frequency (as like a resistive response). So it is ok. 
But the problem with method2 is I have only freedom of defining turn ratio, not the coupling coefficient(k). But I want to work with coupling coefficient(k) than turn ratio.
SO please suggest me, which method is best suited for WPT coil modelling in cadence.

Answer (score 1):

> please suggest me, which method is best suited for WPT coil modelling
>   in cadence

I can't tell you which works best in cadence because I don't use cadence but, I'd stick with the coupled inductor model and set the turns ratio by setting the inductor ratio appropriately i.e. if you want a 10:1 turns ratio, you use a ratio of inductors that is \$(10:1)^2\$ or 100:1.